# Compactness implies finite subcover

Tags: real-analysis

I have a few questions about a proof of the direction $(a) \to (c)$ of the Theorem $2.4.13$ (Heine–Borel Theorem) from [Pons' book (Google Books link)](https://books.google.com/books?id=zrS9BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA88&lpg=PA88&dq=Theorem%202.4.13%20(Heine%E2%80%93Borel%20Theorem)%20Pons&source=bl&ots=x3ol4PiyT1&sig=ACfU3U3uTqpm-_APL0Z3MKMxwwGFi5B_GQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjfj9atrdX0AhWJlGoFHQv3D3EQ6AF6BAgDEAM#v=onepage&q=Theorem%202.4.13%20(Heine%E2%80%93Borel%20Theorem)%20Pons&f=false).

For convenience, I typed up that part of the proof below.

---

Assume $K$ is $\require{enclose}\enclose{horizontalstrike}{\text{compact}}$ closed and bounded and let $\mathcal O$ be an open cover for $K$. Since $a = \inf(K), b = \sup(K) \in K,$ we have $K \subseteq [a, b].$ Now consider $\displaystyle{E = \{x \in [a, b]: K \cap [a, x] \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^NO_{\lambda_i}\}} \ne \varnothing$. Since $a \le x \le b$, by definition $b$ bounds $E$ from above meaning $c = \sup(E)$ exists.

Suppose $c \not \in K$. Then there $\delta > 0$ s.t. with $B_\delta(c) \subseteq K^c.$

$\color{red}{\text{By definition of $c$ and our assumption that $c \not \in K$, we have $a < c < b$ and so $B_\delta(c) \subseteq (a, b)$ since $a, b \in K.$}}$

Since $c = \sup(E)$, exists $y \in E$ with $c - \delta < y$.

$\color{blue}{\text{Using the fact that $B_\delta(c) \subseteq K^c$, it follows that $\displaystyle{K \cap [a, y] = K \cap \left[a, c + \frac{\delta}{2}\right]}$}}$. But then $c + \frac{\delta}{2} \in E$ which contradicts the fact that $\color{brown}{\text{$c$ is the supremum}}$. Thus $c \in K$.

Since $c \in K$, there's an open set $O_\alpha$ with $c \in O_\alpha$. Since $O_\alpha$ is open, exists $\epsilon > 0$ with $(c -\epsilon, c + \epsilon) \subseteq O_\alpha$. Because $c$ is the supremum, there's $d \in E$ with $d \in (c - \epsilon, c)$. By definition of $E$, we have $\displaystyle{K \cap [a, d] \subseteq \bigcup^N_{i = 1} O_{\lambda_i}}$. Since $d \in (c - \epsilon, c + \epsilon)$, it follows $\displaystyle{K \cap [a, c + \epsilon] \subseteq O_\alpha \cup \left(\bigcup^N_{i = 1} O_{\lambda_i}\right)}$.

$\color{green}{\text{If $c < b$, then there are points of $[a, b]$ in $(c, c + \epsilon)$ and the above set inclusion then contradicts the fact that $c = \sup (E)$}}$.

Thus $c = b$ ($c$ cannot be greater than $b$) and the above finite subcover satisfies $\displaystyle{K \cap [a, b] = K \cap [a, c] \subseteq O_\alpha \cup \left(\bigcup^N_{i = 1} O_{\lambda_i}\right)}$.

---

My questions:

- $\color{red}{\text{Part in red}}$ of the text above:

  I am not sure I understand this part. Suppose $c < a$. Then $c$ is not an upper bound. Suppose $c > b$. Then $c$ is not the supremum. Thus $a \le c \le b.$ Now $a, b \in K$  and $c \not \in K$ meaning $a \ne c \ne b$ which implies $a < c < b.$ Since $c - a, b - c$ are positive, we can find some elbow room about $c$ that's inside $(a, b).$ Does that make sense? How does the assumption $c \not \in K$ imply $B_\delta(c) \subseteq (a, b)$? Also, where do we use $B_\delta(c) \subseteq (a, b)$?
- $\color{blue}{\text{Part in blue}}$ of the text above:

  $c - \delta < y \implies \displaystyle{K \cap \left[a, c + \frac{\delta}{2}\right] \subseteq K \cap [a, y]}$. But how does the other inclusion follow? How does  $B_\delta(c) \subseteq K^c$ help?
- $\color{brown}{\text{Part in brown}}$ of the text above:

  Wouldn't it be more precise to say $c + \frac{\delta}{2} \in E$ contradicts the fact that $c$ is an upper bound? As an upper bound, $c$ is supposed to be greater or equal to everything in $E$, but $c + \frac{\delta}{2} \in E$ contradicts that.
- $\color{green}{\text{Part in green}}$ of the text above:

  Suppose $c < a < c + \epsilon$. Then $c$ is not an upper bound. Is that what the part in green is saying?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean “suppose $K$ is closed and bounded”? It doesn’t make sense to suppose $K$ is compact and prove $K$ is compact.

Comment: @MarkSaving, yes.

Comment: @MarkSaving presumably the asker's definition of compactness is closed and bounded, hence why the title says what it says